# Why does Fiona output look different from image?

Tags: qgis, shapely, python-2.7, fiona, hough-transform

I'm trying to export my houghlines as a shapefile, which works. But the output the lines in my shapefile are very different then the generated hough lines that are shown on the image.

Example:

[image: The hough lines that are generated with the program]

The output here is great, beacause I need the corner point of the building.

When I try to save the lines with Fiona, the output (in QGIS) becomes this:

[image]

Wich is a way less elegant result. How do i export the lines exactly like they are shown in the image?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import cv2
from shapely import ops
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString, mapping
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
#from PIL import Image

in_path  = 'D:\\Users\\PdeHaan\\Documents\\TestFase\\Python\\Data\\Test_kernel_error\\t2\\filtered_2871_10476_1_1_1_1.tif'
out_path = 'D:\\Users\\PdeHaan\\Documents\\TestFase\\Python\\Pictures\\hough_lines_TESTTTT.tif'



gray = cv2.imread(in_path)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('D:\\Users\\PdeHaan\\Documents\\TestFase\\Python\\Pictures\\edgess.tif',edges)
minLineLength=40
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=3,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=200,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=30)

black = np.zeros_like(gray) 
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(black, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)


    cv2.imwrite(out_path,black)


#print lines
arraylines = array(lines) 

arraylines = arraylines.astype(float) / 10.0
print arraylines

# Rotate image    
for arrayline in arraylines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in arrayline:
        arrayline[:,0] = 50 - x1
        arrayline[:,1] = 50 - y1
        arrayline[:,2] = 50 - x2
        arrayline[:,3] = 50 - y2    


#print arraylines

# Georeference to CRS        
s_lines = []
for arrayline in arraylines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in arrayline:
        x1 += (2870 * 50)
        y1 += (10474 * 50)
        x2 += (2870 * 50)
        y2 += (10474 * 50)

        s_line = LineString([(x1, y2), (x2, y1)])

        s_lines.append(s_line)

multi_line = MultiLineString(s_lines)

merged_line = ops.linemerge(multi_line)


schema = {
    'geometry': 'LineString',
    'properties': {'id': 'int'}
}

with fiona.open('output_line_kernel.shp', 'w',  'ESRI Shapefile', schema,crs=from_epsg(28992)) as c:
    c.write({
            'geometry': mapping(merged_line),
            'properties': {'id': 0}})
```